# Make user-inputted url into external link in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want users to be able to enter a url and then put a link to that url in my view.

Valid inputs could be e.x. `https://www.google.com/path`, `http://www.google.com`, `www.google.com`

Is there are standard rails way to 1) validate that input is a valid url format and 2) convert that third format to `http://www.google.com` in my views so the external link works?

I don't want to re-invent the wheel if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this out:

```
validates_format_of :website, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))
```

Source: http://intridea.com/2009/2/18/quick-tip-url-validation-in-rails?blog=company

To format a URL that is missing the protocol (http or https), I would do a before_save hook that prepends it if it's missing:

```
before_save :format_url

...

def format_url
  self.website = "http://#{self.website}" unless self.website[/^https?/]    
end
```

Comment: oh, that's really cool. I knew about the URI library, but wasn't sure how to use it.  I put format_url in before_validation so that www.google.com becomes parse-able, but otherwise this seems to work perfectly

Comment: in Rails 4, the modification to the input needs to happen in `before validation` for the `validates :website format:{} to work

Answer (score 1):

The Domainatrix gem comes highly recommended for validating URLs:

https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but seems a little overkill for what I'm doing. also the github summary scares me